# Add custom text to a contact list

Tags: menu-item, contact

I am Using Joomla 3.8. I added some contacts to the system and a menu. The menu contains a menu entry "Contacts" that lists all of the contacts of a certain category. This all works fine and was easy to do using the built-in menu entry types provided by Joomla.

However now I would like to add an additional sentence about e-mail privacy to that contact list. Since the list is generated by Joomla (and is no editable article) I have no idea how to add custom text above or below the contact list.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is it a static bit of text? Can we see a link to your page? Or a screenshot with a bit of photoshop work with what you wish to add?

Comment: Yes a static bit of text. But I think I found a good solution myself. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a very good solution for the problem. Key is the fact that multiple modules can be located at a single position.

I created a new custom module. Using the WYSIWYG editor I put in my e-mail privacy hint (including a link). Then I located that module to the footer position (which was already used for the copyright) in the right order (privacy hint above copyright). I selected to enable this module for the contact list menu/page only.

The result is exactly what I need. An additional advantage of that solution is that I can easily enable for additional menus/pages.

Comment: If you are satisfied with your own solution, you can award yourself the green tick so that this question is not periodically bumped to the front page.